# Performance impact of using short key in JSON file

Tags: json, performance, web-applications, web

In a **web server application**, I use some JSON configuration file. Does anyone have any idea, if using shorter key, what's the performance benefit?

For instance, a long key is "country_code", which value is a country code, an int.
A shorter key is "cc".

**How much performance benefit can we get from using the shorter key? considering network bandwidth, memory...etc**

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on how many copies you need to transmit.

Comment: For network bandwidth saving, I prefer gzip it first, instead of using shorter key.